# Unable to generate a URL for the named route "participants" as such route does not exist

Tags: php, twig, symfony4

I want to add this link in my code :

```
<a href="{{ path('participants', {id: formation.id})  }}" class="btn btn-secondary">La liste des participants</a>
```

And i write this function in my controller :

```
 /**
 * @Route("/admin/formation/{id}/participants", name="participants")
 */
public function participants(Formations $formation)
{
    $participants = $this->repositoryp->findBy(array('id_f_id' => $formation->getId() ));

    return $this->render('Formations/Participants.html.twig', [
        'participants' => $participants,
    ]);
}
```

But it doesn't work. what i need to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example everything is correct. Probably you forget to configure your [routing via annotations](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#creating-routes-as-annotations).

Check `config/routes.yaml`. There should be such configuration:

```
# config/routes.yaml
controllers:
    resource: '../src/Controller/'
    type: annotation
```

Perhaps this config is located in `config/routes/annotations.yaml`.

```
# config/routes/annotations.yaml
controllers:
    resource: '../../src/Controller/'
    type: annotation
```

If this setting is not present in any of these files, add it.

Comment: With an `@Route` you also need to `use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;` in each of the PHP files that have the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

you missed getting id from the request:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/admin/formation/{id}/participants", name="participants")
 */
public function participants(Formations $formation,$id)
{
    $participants = $this->repositoryp->findBy(array('id_f_id' => $id ));

    return $this->render('Formations/Participants.html.twig', [
        'participants' => $participants,
    ]);
}
```

dump $id and you can get id value and then make a repo call like you did.

Changes,

```
public function participants(Formations $formation,$id)
```

and

```
$participants = $this->repositoryp->findBy(array('id_f_id' => $id ));
```

And you are good to go.